# Declaring global throwing Swift function from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to build a small module meant for consumption in Swift, in Objective-C. I'm having problems translating `NSError **` into `throws` on the Swift side.

This is the function definition that I've tried:

```
NSString * _Nullable revHashOfFile(NSURL * _Nonnull url, NSError ** error) __attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error), swift_name("revHash(ofFile:)")));
```

The idea is that this should show up as follows in Swift:

```
public func revHash(ofFile url: URL) throws -> String
```

But for some reason the generated interface contains this:

```
public func revHash(ofFile url: URL, _ error: NSErrorPointer) -> String?
```

*(the reson I'm not writing in Swift is because I need `CommonCrypto` and this is a library so I cannot use bridging headers)*

Comment: As far as I know, global functions are not imported as `throws` function into Swift. Why don't you make it a class method?

Comment: I'm quite new to Swift API design, but too me it didn't seem appropriate since my entire API doesn't contain any defined classes. The api is just one overloaded function: `revHash(of: String) -> String`, `revHash(of: Data) -> String`, `revHash(ofFile: URL) -> String`. I'd be happy to get some pointers to API design best practices in Swift!

Comment: I tried it the other direction to see what Xcode would generate for the obj-c header and this is what I got: `- (NSString * _Nullable)revHashOfFile:(NSURL * _Nonnull)url error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;`

Comment: @vacawama I'm quite new to this, but I think that that definition is a class method. I'm trying to make a global function, which I have learned is defined as a C function.

Comment: The part that I thought might work for you was was the `(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error` part instead of `NSError ** error` that you are using.

Comment: Classes which have only class methods are not so popular in Objective-C frameworks, but you have only two options: Make them methods or Give up importing them as `throws` function.

Comment: @OOPer Objects are not modules.™ This is the reason why you should not do it, if possible, and why it is unpopular in Objective-C. However, if this is the solution …

Comment: I'd say that this a bug, feel free [to file it as such](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: I have filed it as a bug! https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7400

Comment: @vacawama unfortunately, `NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable error` doesn't work either...